# Apply Resilience4j Circuit Breaker for Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

This has been asked multiple times, I have visited all of those questions and still can't seem to get the Circuit Breaker to break.

Here's the Configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class CircuitBreaker {
    @Bean
    public Customizer<ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory> defaultCustomizer() {
        return factory -> factory.configure(id -> {
                id.circuitBreakerConfig(CircuitBreakerConfig.ofDefaults());
                id.timeLimiterConfig(TimeLimiterConfig.custom().timeoutDuration(Duration.ofMillis(200)).build());
            }
        , "myCircuitBreaker");
    }
}
```

The routing:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class SpringApiGatewayApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SpringApiGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder, ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory circuitBreakerFactory) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(p -> p
                        .path("/recipe/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.circuitBreaker(c -> {
                            c.setName("myCircuitBreaker");
                            System.out.println(c.getId());
                        }))
                        .uri("lb://recipe-service")
                )
                .route(p -> p
                        .path("/order/**")
                        .uri("lb://order-service")
                )
                .build();
    }
}
```

which still print `myCircuitBreaker` as expected.
The client API (which does not implement any circuit breaking, as I want the Spring Gateway to handle everything):

```java
    @GetMapping("/port")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getPort() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(300);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(serverPort.toString());
    }
```

and the server responds with `200 OK` (even when ran 20-100 times consecutively) instead of tripping and returning a `503`/`504`.
And the `pom.xml` file:

```
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.6</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
                <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Using `logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.gateway=TRACE` returned this:

```
2023-05-05 18:35:45.403 TRACE 30356 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] o.s.c.gateway.filter.NettyRoutingFilter  : outbound route: 9068368b, inbound: [c68d633f-11] 
2023-05-05 18:35:45.713 TRACE 30356 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] o.s.c.g.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter  : NettyWriteResponseFilter start inbound: 9068368b, outbound: [c68d633f-11] 
2023-05-05 18:35:46.495 TRACE 30356 --- [     parallel-9] o.s.c.g.f.WeightCalculatorWebFilter      : Weights attr: {}
2023-05-05 18:35:46.495 TRACE 30356 --- [     parallel-9] o.s.c.g.h.p.PathRoutePredicateFactory    : Pattern "/recipe/**" matches against value "/recipe/port"
2023-05-05 18:35:46.495 DEBUG 30356 --- [     parallel-9] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Route matched: 4a10df9b-21bd-4d09-b565-3aa824503289
2023-05-05 18:35:46.495 DEBUG 30356 --- [     parallel-9] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Mapping [Exchange: GET http://localhost:8082/recipe/port] to Route{id='4a10df9b-21bd-4d09-b565-3aa824503289', uri=lb://recipe-service, order=0, predicate=Paths: [/recipe/**], match trailing slash: true, gatewayFilters=[[[SpringCloudCircuitBreakerResilience4JFilterFactory name = 'myCircuitBreaker', fallback = [null]], order = 0]], metadata={}}
2023-05-05 18:35:46.495 DEBUG 30356 --- [     parallel-9] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : [c68d633f-12] Mapped to org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler@644cf7a6
2023-05-05 18:35:46.495 DEBUG 30356 --- [     parallel-9] o.s.c.g.handler.FilteringWebHandler      : Sorted gatewayFilterFactories: [[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RemoveCachedBodyFilter@2bfa5678}, order = -2147483648], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.AdaptCachedBodyGlobalFilter@5b4b6f3b}, order = -2147482648], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter@61375dff}, order = -1], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardPathFilter@2178d296}, order = 0], [[SpringCloudCircuitBreakerResilience4JFilterFactory name = 'myCircuitBreaker', fallback = [null]], order = 0], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter@5b8b9b2d}, order = 10000], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ReactiveLoadBalancerClientFilter@7ec68821}, order = 10150], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.LoadBalancerServiceInstanceCookieFilter@220a5163}, order = 10151], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WebsocketRoutingFilter@58c80957}, order = 2147483646], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyRoutingFilter@6158113e}, order = 2147483647], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardRoutingFilter@7a7bb083}, order = 2147483647]]
2023-05-05 18:35:46.495 TRACE 30356 --- [     parallel-9] o.s.c.g.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter   : RouteToRequestUrlFilter start
2023-05-05 18:35:46.499 TRACE 30356 --- [     parallel-9] s.c.g.f.ReactiveLoadBalancerClientFilter : ReactiveLoadBalancerClientFilter url before: lb://recipe-service/recipe/port
2023-05-05 18:35:46.499 TRACE 30356 --- [     parallel-9] s.c.g.f.ReactiveLoadBalancerClientFilter : LoadBalancerClientFilter url chosen: http://LAPTOP-42E0D7RO:8091/recipe/port
```

which the CircuitBreaker filter does pop up.

Here's the documentation for Spring Cloud Circuit Breaker 3.0.1 : https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker/docs/current/reference/html/

I know I can move everything to the `application.properties` or `application.yaml` and it will probably work, but I want to know why it doesn't.

- Additional info: I'm running on Windows 11, Spring Boot  2.7.10, project initialized with Spring Initializr.

Comment: Are you making your request to the /recipe/** path which has the circuit breaker?

Comment: @orser Yes, I'm making the request to that path through the Gateway. Everything return as expected, except for the 200 OK code. You can also see it in the log: `Pattern "/recipe/**" matches against value "/recipe/port"`

Comment: Can you try using spring boot 3?

Comment: @orser I tried that in the first place. Spring boot 3 work very weirdly with Netflix Eureka. That's why I downgraded it.

Comment: I am using pretty much the same config with Spring boot 3 and everything works fine. Maybe there is some auto configuration missing if you use boot 2

Comment: @orser I've switched to Spring Boot 3.0.6, everything autoconfigured from Spring Initializr, even the Resilience4j circuit breaker, nothing added by hand. Same problem remained. Can you elaborate on how you test the circuit breaker? If possible, can I get access to the sample?